# On the multiplicative overhead 2 in the construction of pairwise independent hashing from ERCs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, circuit-depth, cryptography

A standard method of constructing pairwise independent hash function from error-correcting code is as follows:

Given a generator matrix $G$ of a distance-$d$ linear error-correcting code mapping $m$ bits to $n$ bits, we have its transpose $G^T$ a perfect $l$-exposure-resilient function, $l=n-d+1$. Distance-$d$ ERCs can be implemented by depth-$d$ circuits. Reversing the direction of wires in a circuit of an ERC and interchanging its XOR gates and fan-out gates generates an circuit for an $l$-ERF. Thus the connection: ERC --> constant size pairwise independent hash functions in $\frak{F}_2$ --> ERF gives a pairwise independent hashing in depth-$2d$ circuit.

The question is, can the overhead 2 be eliminated? That is, can we construct a depth-$d$ circuit for a pairwise independent hashing from a depth-$d$ circuit of an ERC? Since any circuit for an ERC is a superconcentrator, directly constructing a family of pairwise indepent hash functions from a superconcentrator might work, but I have no idea how to verify this.

---

Maybe defining something like "partial universal hashing" in analogy to partial superconcentrator would work. But how to do so?